# http://testng.org/ is unavailable

Tags: testng, testng-eclipse

I am facing the issue that non of the testng sites are accessible .Please note that all other sites are working for me . And this is not a firewall effect .
Because of this i am unable to install testng from eclipse market place .

Is anyone facing the same issues ?

How to install testng on eclipse when http://testng.org/ is unavailable . Is there any other reference available ?

Comment: https://isitup.org/testng.org

Answer (score 2):

The website is apparently down right now. This site helps you to know if a website being inaccessible has anything to do with your network: www.isitdownrightnow.com/